# Any idea for executing Selenium webdriver + Java/Python tests from Cloud

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cloud, automated-tests

I can't found any question/answer about that (probably I don't know how to find it...)

Could somebody give me a global idea to execute +200 Selenium webdriver tests (Python) from cloud servers/tools?

Thanks!!

rgzl

Answer (score 1):

Another way is [Saucelabs](https://saucelabs.com/), using this service you'll be able to just send your Selenium

> Java/Python tests

to their Cloud infrastructure for execution. The benefits of such testing are obvious – no need to waste time and resources setting up and maintaining your own VM farm, and additionally you can run your test suite in various browsers in parallel. Also no need to share any sensitive data, source code and databases.

As said in [this acticle](http://pivotallabs.com/selenium-in-the-cloud-saucelabs-com-and-the-saucelabsadapter/):

> Of course inserting this roundtrip across the Internet is not without cost. The penalty of running Selenium tests this way is that they run quite slowly, typically about 3 times slower in my experience. This means that this is not something that individual developers are going to do from their workstations.

To ease the integration of this service into your projects, maybe you'll have to write a some kind of  saucelabs-adapter, that will do the necessary SSH tunnel setup/teardown and Selenium configuration, automatically as part of a test.

And for a better visualization:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a global idea:

Use Amazon Web Services.

Using AWS, you can have a setup like this:

- 1 Selenium Grid.  IP: X.X.X.X
- 100 Selenium nodes connecting to X.X.X.X:4444/wd/register
  Each Selenium node has a node config, running 2 maxSessions at once. (depending on size of course)
- Have also, a Continuous integration server like Jenkins, run your Python tests Against X.X.X.X grid.